# How to properly setup a POST spring rest template by passing in parameters and return json?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am a bit new to spring and I am having issues calling a rest service using post to a ur in spring by using spring templates
I am not sure how to properly pass in data into the rest template and how to get json data out currently i get 415 unsupport media type error.

So the RestservicesURL.signupurl = "abc.com/signup 
the param would be = "name=john?email=john@doe.com?password=john" (which is acquired  by @RequestParam Map by spring)
The response I need to get is a JSON object and I am not sure how to do this;

```
public void signUp(Map<String, String> param) {
    try {
        callService(RestServicesUrl.SIGNUP_URL, param);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the rest template call

```
public static void callService(String url, Map<String, String> data) throws Exception {
    List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.ALL);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers); 


    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

    rest.postForObject(url, entity, byte[].class);              

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to post JSON as well as receive it?

Based on your "data" variable it looks like you might be trying to send JSON.  I see you have "ALL" set on the acceptable media types, if you're posting JSON and expect to receive it back, you should put the acceptable media type and Content-Type headers to "application/json".  I believe Spring has constants for these.  This could be the cause of your 415 unsupported mediatype error.

As for creating your JSON, you should strongly consider a serialization framework to convert your Java objects into JSON for you and vice versa - Jackson is a very popular option and is tied closely into Spring's functionality for this, see details here: [RestTemplate + Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328492/resttemplate-jackson)

If that's not an option, you'll need to figure out a way to get your data object converted into the appropriate HTTP request with an [HTTPMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html).

Comment: I am trying to post a url with parameters and receive json back.

Comment: This may help then: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/70845-sending-post-parameters-with-resttemplate-requests However, still would be a good idea to look into Jackson.