# How to return String object through Jackson Parser from Java instance

Tags: java, json, string, spring, resttemplate

Say I have:

```
ReportExecution executionRequestBody = new ReportExecution();
```

I need something to parse the instance in a way that it would be parsed in JSON format but having textual outlook.

```
String b = JacksonParserParse(executionRequestBody);
```

Where I would be able to do something like:

```
logger.info(b);
```

Output:

```
{"reportUnitUri": "/path/to/report",
"async": "true",
"freshData": "false",
"saveDataSnapshot": "false",
"outputFormat": "html",
"interactive": "true",
"ignorePagination": "false",
"pages": "1-5"
}
```

The ultimate task is to simply insert this String into HTTP request body in Spring `RestTemplate HttpEntity.` So if there is less thorny way I am more than happy to hear alternative.

Now I can do simple mapping but that usually results in .json file in the filesystem which I do not really know how to plug into my `HttpEntity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is integration RestTemplate with Jackson. This can easily be done and is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328492/resttemplate-jackson) SO question.

Comment: @Aubergine Happy to hear it :)!

Comment: Though this automatic object mapping, cant work with nested json values quite well or either i cant find suitable data structure - list of list of map rofl, my next question tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easily using [ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) from `Jackson`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ReportExecution executionRequestBody = new ReportExecution(); 
String b = mapper.writeValueAsString(executionRequestBody);
System.out.println(b);
```